# Adding to Python Path Dir

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pythonpath

I have figured out how to temporarily append the path dir

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('c:\\code')
```

... But how do I add a file permanently? I tried the following...

```
import os, sys
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\code
```

Comment: That would involve modifying your `PATH` in your Windows Settings somewhere.

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically from within python? Or can you just set the environment variable externally like usual?

Comment: I looked externally and I am at a loss. I thought there was a way through programming in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid setting environment variables, you can add a folder to your path by creating a `.pth` file in the folder `%APPDATA%\Python\Python34\site-packages` (you may have to create the folder).

For example, with `%APPDATA%\Python\Python34\site-packages\anything.pth` containing the single line

```
c:\code
```

... and `c:\code` containg the file `woof.py` with the following line:

```
MIAOW = "chirrup"
```

... we can check that it all works:

```
>>> from woof import MIAOW
>>> MIAOW
'chirrup'
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!!!! I ran through your steps and accidentally did .path - after I fixed that typo it worked. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the easiest way to set the environment variable is by following **Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables** and editing PYTHONPATH manually. You can simply append it in the dialog box.